# Suppress directory names being listed with DIR

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to list the files in a folder but not sub-folders. `DIR` enables you to list specific types of files (hidden, archive ready etc) and also only folders but I cannot see how to list only files.

I need the following statement to return files for further processing, but folder names are messing things up!

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b %csvPath%') do (
)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`dir /b /a-d` will give you files without directories. Note there is no space between `/a-d`. The '-' says "NOT" directories.

From the `dir /?` help information:

```
  /A          Displays files with specified attributes.
  attributes   D  Directories                R  Read-only files
               H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
               S  System files               -  Prefix meaning not
  /B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).
```

Comment: Fantastic. I did actually read the help files but it was at the end of a long day! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: can we ignore the file extension from result too?

Comment: Does not work on my Windows 10 Enterprise against a mapped drive. Does work on a local drive

Answer (score 8):

```
dir /b /s /a-d
```

`/s` lists every directory and all subdirectories containing files, and (a-d) without empty directories.

```
dir /b /s /a-d /p
```

`/p` pause

```
dir /b /s /a-d > list.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
dir /b /a-d
```

Which will suppress directories being listed.

The `/A` switch has a few other options to assist with filtering:

```
/A          Displays files with specified attributes.
attributes   D  Directories                R  Read-only files
             H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
             S  System files               I  Not content indexed files
             L  Reparse Points             -  Prefix meaning not
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `dir /B /A-D` to get files only.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `/A-D` option:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /A-D /b %csvPath%') do ( )
```