# Batch File; List files in directory, only filenames?

Tags: batch-file

This is probably a very simple question, but I'm having trouble with it.

I am trying to write a Batch File and I need it to list all the files in a certain directory. The `dir` command will do this, but it also gives a bunch of other information; I want it to list ONLY the *file names* and exclude anything else.

I just want the output to look like this:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress directory names being listed with DIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164184/suppress-directory-names-being-listed-with-dir)

Answer (score 341, accepted):

The full command is:

```
dir /b /a-d
```

Let me break it up;

Basically the `/b` is what you look for.

`/a-d` will exclude the directory names.

---

For more information see `dir /?` for other arguments that you can use with the `dir` command.

Comment: Is OK for me :)    `dir /b /a-d > tmp.txt`

Comment: It doesn't work with `/S` to get file names of sub-directories also.

Comment: @xyroid did you read the seltene `/a-d will the exclude directory names`?

Comment: It's not excluding if I want to print names of sub-directories' files.

Comment: This was very close to what I needed. I needed the absolute paths and recursion into subdirectories. Here is what I used: `dir /B /A-D /S`

Comment: @Stephan, i try to find multiple file, but when echo the output, the result still showing the path after using /A-D. My code `set /p yy=Please enter cycle Year (YYYY) : 
set /p mm=Please enter cycle Month (MM) : 
set /p dd=Please enter cycle Date (DD) :


cd /d E:\
rem count the files
dir /b *%yy%%mm%%dd%_*_P*.tgz /s 2> nul | find "" /v /c > %temp%\count
set /p _count=<%temp%\count
rem cleanup
del %temp%\count
rem output the number of files
echo Files found : %_count%
dir /B /A-D *%yy%%mm%%dd%_*_P*.tgz /s`

Comment: @afifi That's because you use `/s`  (that's called FQFN (Full Qualified File Name)). How else would you distinguish files with the same name in different folders? If you really need only the names recursive (think twice about it), use `for /r %a in (*%yy%%mm%%dd%_*_P*.tgz) do @echo %~nxa` (some other answers here also use similar `for` loops).

Comment: Just to clarify (as some comments complain about "folders do show"): the command in my answer **does** exclude folders. It shows files only. That it shows the files (note: no folders, just files) **including** their path, is a completely different thing and only occurs when `/s` is used (recursive).

Comment: hi @Stephan there any alternative to generate filepath? I am using the one you wrote and take 3 minutes for around 20000 files..  seems to much ..

Comment: I also used PowerShell, same .. its slow..

Comment: I found robocopy very very fast.. but i cannot make export with `file '%path%'`  someone know how? with robocopy?

Answer (score 44):

You can also try this:

```
for %%a in (*) do echo %%a
```

Using a `for` loop, you can `echo` out all the file names of the current directory.

To print them directly from the console:

```
for %a in (*) do @echo %a
```

Answer (score 18):

- Why not use **`where`** instead **`dir`**?

---

In command line:

```bat
for /f tokens^=* %i in ('where .:*')do @"%~nxi"
```

In bat/cmd file:

```bat
@echo off 

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('where .:*')do %%~nxi
```

- Output:

---

```bat
file_0003.xlsx
file_0001.txt
file_0002.log
```

```bat
where .:*
```

- Output:

---

```bat
G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\file_0003.xlsx
G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\file_0001.txt
G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\file_0002.log
```

For recursively:

```bat
where /r . *
```

- Output:

---

```bat
G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\file_0003.xlsx
G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\file_0001.txt
G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\file_0002.log
G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\Sub_dir_001\file_0004.docx
G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\Sub_dir_001\file_0005.csv
G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\Sub_dir_001\file_0006.odt
```

- For loop get path and name:

---

- In command line:

```bat
for /f tokens^=* %i in ('where .:*')do @echo/ Path: %~dpi ^| Name: %~nxi
```

- In bat/cmd file:

```bat
@echo off 

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('where .:*')do echo/ Path: %%~dpi ^| Name: %%~nxi
```

- Output:

---

```bat
 Path: G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\ | Name: file_0003.xlsx
 Path: G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\ | Name: file_0001.txt
 Path: G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\ | Name: file_0002.log
```

---

- For loop get path and name recursively:

In command line:

```bat
for /f tokens^=* %i in ('where /r . *')do @echo/ Path: %~dpi ^| Name: %~nxi
```

In bat/cmd file:

```bat
@echo off 

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('where /r . *')do echo/ Path: %%~dpi ^| Name: %%~nxi
```

- Output:

---

```bat
 Path: G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\ | Name: file_0003.xlsx
 Path: G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\ | Name: file_0001.txt
 Path: G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\ | Name: file_0002.log
 Path: G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\Sub_dir_001\ | Name: file_0004.docx
 Path: G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\Sub_dir_001\ | Name: file_0005.csv
 Path: G:\SO_en-EN\Q23228983\Sub_dir_001\ | Name: file_0006.odt
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Where](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)**

  [√] **[Where sample](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**

Comment: @kakyo Thanks for comment... current path == . And all files == *

Comment: Thanks too, for test!

Answer (score 14):

1.Open notepad

2.Create new file

3.type bellow line

```
dir /b > fileslist.txt
```

4.Save "`list.bat`"

Thats it. now you can copy & paste this "`list.bat`" file any of your folder location and double click it, it will create a "`fileslist.txt`" along with that directory folder and file name list.

**Sample Output:**
[image]

Note: If you want create file name list along with sub folder, then you can create batch file with bellow code.

```
dir /b /s > fileslist.txt
```

Comment: What if I do not want the output file "fileslist.txt" to be included in the list?

Comment: ... above the `dir` line use `del fileslist.txt`

Comment: @Behnam then exclude it using `findstr` i.e `dir /b /s | findstr /VI "filelist.txt" > filelist.txt"`

Comment: this is incorrect as an answer to the question, because it will include the directory names as well, unlike `dir /b /a-d`

Answer (score 8):

If you need the subdirectories too you need a "dir" command and a "For" command

```
dir /b /s DIRECTORY\*.* > list1.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (list1.txt) do echo %%~nxA >> list.txt

del list1.txt
```

put your root directory in dir command. It will create a list1.txt with full path names and then a list.txt with only the file names.

Comment: why? This is unwanted overhead. just do `for /R %%i in (*) do echo (%%~nxi)>list.txt`

Answer (score 4):

create a batch-file with the following code:

```
dir %1 /b /a-d > list.txt
```

Then drag & drop a directory on it and the files inside the directory will be listed in list.txt

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10:

1. open cmd
2. change directory where you want to create text file(movie_list.txt) for the folder (d:\videos\movies)
3. type following command

   d:\videos\movies> **dir /b /a-d > movie_list.txt**

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell dir uses Get-ChildItem, which you can filter using Powershell commands:

dir | select { $_.Name }

Comment: I am not sure what to do now. You helped me but this question is targetting Batch not Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

dir /s/d/a:-d "folderpath*.*" > file.txt

And, lose the /s if you do not need files from subfolders