# How to list files in a directory, just the files, not other unnecessary stuff like the time modified?

Tags: list, file, batch-file, directory

I am trying to make a program for puzzles and wanted people to download them and put them in the puzzle directory.

I used the `dir` command and using it shows unnecessary details like the date modified and the `.` and `..` folders.

Comment: `dir /b /a-d` should do what you want. see `dir /?` from the prompt for documentation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228983/batch-file-list-files-in-directory-only-filenames Hopefully this helps

Comment: Please write an answer so that I can accept the answer, as this helped my problem.