# Android.mk, Windows Shell: How to get the list of all directories and subdirectories without complete path

Tags: android, windows, shell, makefile, android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) //returns jni
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := jni\shared\Core\filters\supplemental jni\shared\Core\aspect_ratio
jni\shared\Core\cache jni\shared\Core\doc_axis jni\shared\Core\kiss_fft
jni\shared\Core\perspective jni\shared\Core\supplemental jni\shared\Core\types
```

I have hardcoded the value for LOCAL_C_INCLUDES. However, I'd like to use windows shell command to get this value for LOCAL_C_INCLUDES. I researched on this for over 2 hours but couldn't find any.

[How do i get a list of folders and subfolders without the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078421/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-folders-and-subfolders-without-the-files)

[Suppress directory names being listed with DIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164184/suppress-directory-names-being-listed-with-dir)

```
ALLFOLDERS := $(shell dir $(LOCAL_PATH)\shared\Core /b /s /ad)
```

The above command gives me the entire path of directories and subdirectories. However, I require only the path from the current directory i.e jni\shared\Core\filters and not the entire path starting from D:\ etc.